# Libraries not installed when copying APK to /system/app on KitKat

Tags: android, system, libraries, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm attempting to add an APK to `/system/app` on KitKat.

After mounting the `/system` partition, copying an APK over, and rebooting, it seems the APK libraries are not getting copied into `/data/app-lib`.

Weirdly, reinstalling 'over' the APK via ADB causes the libraries to be copied, and it works.

I've encountered the same behaviour when building the APK as part of the ROM.

How do I get the system to install libraries for system apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an APK to `/system/app`, you should also extract its libraries and put it in `/system/lib`, reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/v86sYS3Orow

As far as I know this has always being the case and not 4.4 specific

Comment: Thanks. Doing it manually seems to work, but it's a cumbersome process particularly for 3rd parts APKs. Are you aware of any way to get this to happen when building AOSP?

Comment: @user2424511 you probably can do it with coding/scripting, but I've no experience with that

Comment: Have you any idea why for some apps, libs not copied into /system/lib when building aosp? (Also the lib folder is present on correct path!) @user2424511

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a 3rd party app, the library could not be found even it was placed in the /system/lib/ folder. The solution was to move it into the **/system/vendor/lib/** folder.